# Binary Image, Concentrations of White Dots with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Given a binary image of black, with a few sporadic white dots, I'm looking for a way to "lasso" a majority of the white dots inside a bounding rectangle. Consider this image:

[image]

See how not **all** of the dots are enclosed, but just the clusters (or set of clusters) where there are clearly more white dots than anywhere else?

I already know how to [put a bounding box around all of the white dots](http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/10/opencv-bounding-box-skew-angle/) with OpenCV. Can anyone direct me as to how I can analyze this image for **one big concentration of dots**, ignoring any peripheral dots which are not really part of a group?

**N.B.:** This bounding box doesn't have to be skew. Even a convex hull would be nice as output.

I can adjust the size, color, alpha, location, density, etc. of these dots. So if your thoughts involve doing something with these dots in order to process them, that might work.

Comment: `I understand that phrase is hard to quantify`. Until you figure out how to quantify this, we don't really even know what you want. For example, you left out a dot right on the top edge of the rectangle. How come? Why is the rectangle you drew better one that would have included this dot? Likewise, there is a fairly lonely dot (qualitatively speaking) included near the left edge of the rectangle. Why is the rectangle you drew better than a smaller one which would have excluded that dot? Once you can quantify this, that process should suggest an algorithm for you.

Comment: @SchighSchagh Maybe that is best left out. If such a suggestion has something such as an adjustable density constant, then I can use that to quantify a "cluster".

Comment: "*there are clearly more white dots than anywhere else?*" Oh, rly? How do you tell =). Implementing "common sense" is not that easy, and it tends to be very subjective. For example, I would exclude the top dot and include the left one, I think it would increase density inside the box.

Comment: Even without the phrase, you still need some way to quantify it. I don't know what you are using to create this metric for the box that you drew, so how can a computer hope to? If you say "include all dots that are within x pixels of each other as a group", that will give you a metric that will allow you to build it. Answer that question and you should be able to solve your problem.
tl; dr: luk32 wrote it

Comment: Got it. I guess I'll be rolling my own.

Comment: @Olivier Well, all that being said, I think it is a nice and interesting question, although not focused on the real problem which is, what would be a good method to find clusters of points. I think there are some algorithms in the area of classification problems. It really is non-trivial. You can check this out for some resources: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis. Btw. a nice quote: "*According to Vladimir Estivill-Castro, the notion of a "cluster" cannot be precisely defined, which is one of the reasons why there are so many clustering algorithms*".

Comment: I would apply histograms in the binary image to detect the max number of white dots for columns and rows. After, i will try to search in these histograms the best number of combinations....

Comment: @luk32 I forgot about K-means clustering! Thank you for that helpful link.

Comment: It can be interesting http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/back_projection/back_projection.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is sort of a 1-cluster detection algorithm, where outlier detection is important. Clustering algorithms in general are designed and tuned to produce more than one cluster; a portion of them (k-means for example) do not even handle outliers. If you decide to use a real clustering algorithm, try [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) and set it to detect 1 cluster - it has outlier detection ability.

Otherwise, you can consider your problem as a metric maximization problem.

You want a metric that is rewarded for data density, but also rewarded for box size (so you don't end up with a 1x1 box). I propose something along the lines of:

`metric_to_maximize = White_Dot_Density * Area^x`, where `x` is calibrated ad hoc.

Another idea that may work is to divide the image into m x n box-rectangles. Calculate each box's average density. Pick the top x% (or all rectangles that have `density>threshold`). Create a bounding box around these "good boxes" without including too much additional area.

Comment: Whoa! Funny when I rolled my own solution, I used your second idea without ever noticing your suggestion, until now.